# Relationship between Continuity and Countability

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

This is a consequence of one of the problems in elementary real analysis that I am attempting to solve. I have this doubt.

Suppose $f$ is a continuous map from the reals to the reals. If the set $S=${$f(x)|x\in A$} is countable, is the set $S'=${$f(x+1)|x\in A$} countable? Here $A$ is just a subset of $R$.

Well, the question may seem a bit artificial but let me also share the initial question which caused this doubt.

The original question is: Suppose $f$ is continuous such that $f(x)$ is rational iff $f(x+1)$ is irrational. Show such an $f$ cannot exist.

My method:
Suppose such an $f$ exists. A quick thinking tells us that it suffices to consider a restricted domain [$0,1$] only. Consider the set of rationals, $Q$, in this domain. Clearly $f(Q)$ is countable. Consider those irrationals for which $f$ is rational. This particular range of $f$ also is countable as it is a subset of rationals. So we are left with those irrational points in this domain, at which $f$ is irrational. If we can somehow show that the range of $f$ on this particular domain is countable, then it follows that range of $f$ is countable for all real points and hence $f$ is not continuous by IVT.

This is where I am facing a hurdle. I have to prove that the range of $f$ on the final particular domain i.e. set of all irrationals at which $f$ is irrational, is also countable. I figured out that considering any point $x$ in this domain, where $x$ is irrational, if $f(x)$ is irrational, then $f(x+1)$ is rational, so the set {$f(x+1)$} is countable. Does this imply that the range of $f$ when we are concentrating only those irrational points at which $f$ is irrational, is also countable?

Comment: Please note that $f$ is defined at $x+1$ because right after reading the first few lines, one may be tempted to say "How can we conclude that $S'$ at all is non-null?" That's not the case, please note this.

Comment: For the original question, [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651379/no-cont-function-f-colon-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-with-fx-rational-iff-fx).

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading the question wrong, but couldn't you take max(0,x), which takes on the value 0 in the unit interval to the left of 0 but a continuum of values in the unit interval to the right?

Comment: Thank you for the solution thread. Seems it was pretty straightforward. Now that I have got a solution, I am relieved, but at the same time, I need to find an answer to my question. Let's see if anyone gives any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be zero on the nonpositive numbers and then the identity on the nonnegative numbers.

If you take $A=[-1,0]$, $|f(A)|=|\{0\}|=1$, but $|f(A+1)|=|[0,1]|=|\Bbb R|$.

(Here I abuse notation a little by writing $A+1=\{x+1\mid x\in A\}$)

Comment: It could be that you intended "countably infinite" rather than "(at most) countable." Let me know if so, and I can delete and/or correct myself.

Comment: I meant countably infinite. And also, your function isn't continuous, is it?

Comment: @AranyaDey Thanks for the clarification. It is certainly continuous. (Did you draw it?)

Comment: +1. For cutting through the clutter and seeing that the answer is obvious!

Comment: Hmm, so it happens that the method I was pursuing will not be applicable here. Thank you.

Comment: @AranyaDey OK, glad to have your confirmation. I wasn't sure it was what you wanted :)